# how to use multiple datasources with spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I read all the related questions and tried all of them but still can't make my configuration straight.

I've two databases and i want to use them as datasources in my application.

Here is my context file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="firstDataSource" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/firstDS"   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="secondDataSource" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/secondDS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean name="persistenceProvider" class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="thisEntityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="firstDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.a.b.first.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value= "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="firstPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="persistenceProvider"></property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.generate_statistics = true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
            <!--hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-->
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="otherEntityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="secondDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.a.b.second.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value= "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="secondPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="persistenceProvider"></property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.generate_statistics = true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
            <!--hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-->
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="thisTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="thisEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="otherTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="otherEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="thisTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="otherTransactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.a.b.first.intf" entity-manager-factory-ref="thisEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.a.b.second.intf" entity-manager-factory-ref="otherEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="otherTransactionManager" />
```

Problem is when i try to use a repository interface which is located under package **com.a.b.second.intf**, it goes to **firstDataSource** and throws a SQLSyntaxErrorException with message "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". Because there is no such table in the first database.

There is a line in tho logs for each **EntityManagerFactory**, saying

> Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
>   'default'

And in the next line it prints **PersistenceUnitInfo** for this **EntityManagerFactory**. The "Non JTA datasource" property of the PersistenceUnitInfo is same for both EntityManagerFactories. I guess that means both persistence units uses the same datasource.

What am i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: @RobertNiestroj i think my xml configuration is the same. or i'am missing some little detail. can you take a look at my configuration?

Comment: Turns out the problem is in my context.xml file.


`<ResourceLink name="jdbc/firstDS" global="jdbc/firstDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>`

`<ResourceLink name="jdbc/secondDS" global="jdbc/firstDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>`
The second datasource's global property points the first datasource. So every time i make a jndi lookup it gets the wrong datasource.
Fool copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your service layer you should have something like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional("thisTransactionManager")
public class ThisService{

   @Autowired
   private com.a.b.first.intf.Repo1 repo1;
}

@Service
@Transactional("otherEntityManagerFactory")
public class OtherService{

   @Autowired
   private com.a.b.second.intf.Repo1 repo1;
}
```

This way, when you call a service method, the `TransactionInterceptor` can load the appropriate transaction manager, associated to the `EntityManagerFactory` you want to operate with.

Comment: Vlad Mihalcea i tried that, still the same exception. I think the problem here isn't about choosing the right EntityManagerFactory. When creating the second EntityManagerFactory, it's persistence unit gets the wrong datasource.

Comment: That's strange, because you specified the `dataSource` property of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Try adding a break-point into LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to see if it loads the right DataSource.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem, I debug the second data source and everything is fine with the second configurations but when I want to read from tables it throws `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.